# Sufficient Existence of a CPTP map based on piecewise state mappings

Tags: quantum-information, mathematics, linear-algebra, quantum-error-correction

Suppose I want to determine whether there exists a CPTP map, $\mathcal{E}$, such that $\mathcal{E}(\rho_i) \rightarrow \rho_i^{'}$ for $i \in S$. I'm specifically interested in the case where $|S| = 2$, but I'll ask the more general case anyway. What are necessary and sufficient conditions to show that there exists a valid quantum channel that respects the above?

Comment: Qubits or beyond? And what kind of condition are you looking for? This seems a bit unfocused, because, well, the channel will be completely positive if and only if it is completely positive. -- Also, you title ask about "sufficient", while your question asks about "necessary and sufficient", which do you care about?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be rephrased as finding if there is a Choi state (positive semidefinite) with a number of linear constraints (trace preserving + your linear conditions). This is a semidefinite program, and thus can be solved for efficiently.

In the general case, I doubt there is direct "if and only" conditions. On the other hand, if your input-output-relation completely specifies the Choi state (i.e. you are given the output of $D_\mathrm{in}^2$ linearly independent inputs), you can just reconstruct the Choi state and check whether it is positive.